# Need an Example of Django big File upload with upload file handler method

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-file-upload

In one of my django project I am trying to upload files. Files can be video files and can be big as 20 MB. I am trying to upload it with `celery` and `upload_file_handler` method given in django docs.

What I did is it.

```
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    video = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="video")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In forms.py

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    video = forms.FileField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        exclude = ['user']

    def clean_video(self):
        video = self.cleaned_data['video']
        if video and video._size > (10 * 1024 * 1024):
            raise forms.ValidationError("only 10 MB video is allowed")
        return self.cleaned_data['video']
```

In View.py

```
class CreateDigitalAssetsView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    template_name = "video_create.html"
    form_class = VideoForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("video_url")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        video = form.cleaned_data['video']
    
        if video:
            handle_uploaded_file(video)
            # stuck here what to do next.

    def handle_uploaded_file(f):
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(video.name)
        with open('media/video/'+filename, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
```

I am stuck here what to do next after calling `handled_uploaded_file`. Please guide me how can i use this written file using `hanldle_uploaded_file` to save in django model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return the path of the created file (relative to the /media root) from your handle_uploaded_file function, and then save that to the model's video field.

So something like:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(video.name)
    relative_path = "video/%s" % filename
    full_path = "media/%s" % relative_path
    with open(full_path, 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    return relative_path

def form_valid(self, form):
    ...

    if video:
         relative_path = handle_uploaded_file(video)
         form.instance.video = relative_path
         form.instance.save()
```

Comment: Tried this, Working fine on local. Thanks. But it is giving IO error on server called No such directory `"media/%s" % relative_path` exists.

Comment: Sounds like the media root on your server is in a different place.  Does your settings.py contain a MEDIA_ROOT entry?  If so you should use that as the basis instead of "media/".  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root for details.

Comment: Yes, You was right. MEDIA_ROOT was pointing to BASE_DIR+media